# Pynest ImportError: no module named nest

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, importerror, nest-simulator

Today I got PyNest working, after I followed the instructions about installation etc. from their [official site](http://www.nest-initiative.org/index.php/PyNEST). My problem is that I have to run the following command before I can successfully import nest, otherwise I get an "ImportError: No module named nest" :

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/nest/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I found about this command on the official link I gave you above, but I don't understand why this happens. What I can guess is that, this command "shows" where my nest/python files are, but how can I make this command permanent, so I won't have to run in before every trial?

EDIT1: I tried @SumitGupta 's answer and I can now import it when I run python from a terminal, but I get the same error when I try to import nest from Geany or iPython.

(i use Ubuntu 12.04 through VMware virtualization from win8.1 if it matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the trick was to install nest in a directory like: '/home/username/opt/nest' cause otherwise nest won't find python by itself. For example this didn't work: '/~/opt/nest'
Also, **be sure to install all the required libraries before the installation (libgsl,libncurse etc.)**. If you do these two things, you will probably never meet any of my problems.

- For Geany I could not find a way to change PYTHONPATH but for Spyder, there is an option in 'Tools' that's pretty easy to use (you just find your pythonpath directory manually)
- For iPython, I followed these [instructions](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-) and entered my path instead of '~/code/eol_hsrl_python' and '~/hsrl_config'

Answer (score 1):

try adding it in *.profile* or     *.bashrc* or *.bashrc_profile* whatever exists depending upon which is called finally  , in Ubuntu i guess its .bashrc .  These files will be unde user's home

Comment: Thanks that worked when I run python from a terminal and import nest, but for some reason I get the same error when I run it through an IDE (Geany for example)

Comment: I m not completely sure , but check if the IDE  got specific settings for PYTHONPATH like eclipse got!